# Exact copy from 1 sheet to another

Tags: excel, copy, excel-2010

In excel 2010, I want to copy sheet 1, including all formatting and data, page setups, page breaks etc onto sheet2.  In summary I want to do an exact copy of sheet1 on sheet2 through to sheet7.  Ideally I want to insert a command click button on sheet1, so that once I have finished inputting data I can click the button and duplicate the information on each sheet. Any ideas?

Comment: Instead of inserting a button and defining a macro for it, you could much more easily right click on the worksheet tab and choose to copy the sheet.

Comment: But if you really want the button, you'd record as a macro that very action of duplicating the sheet.

Comment: Do you have Sheet2 to Sheet7 in the existing workbook already  ?

Comment: Thanks Anson.  I have recorded the macro like you said.  The issue im having is I already have sheets 1-7 on the workbook. If I run the recorded macro it adds another sheet.  I just want sheets 2-7 to update the same as sheet1.

Comment: Spent the last 3hours searching for an answer.  Honestly though this would be easy.  No luck at present

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,

```
Sub test()
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 2 To 7
        Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Copy Sheets("Sheet" & i).Cells
    Next i
End Sub
```

As an alternative solution I think you should create a button and assign the code below to it.

This will select all the sheets while you're on sheet1 and then whatever changes you make to sheet1 will automatically be available on all sheets instantly.

```
Sub test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Sheets
        If ws.Visible Then ws.Select
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Imran.  I tried your method.  Again adds another sheet and doesn't update sheets 2-7

Comment: Imran.  I have everything working in regards to copying sheet1 to sheet 2-7.  The only thing I cant work out is the page breaks.  I want the page break preview to be the same as sheet1. Hopefully this helps

Comment: Select all sheets and insert the page break it should do for all.

Comment: Imran.  I want it to be automatic.  So where ever i set the page break on sheet1 it automatically sets the same on sheets 2-7.  So once all data is inputted into sheet1 i can hit the button it copies the data, then I will have another button which prints all 7sheets

Comment: @MatthewRisidor It turns out you can select all sheets and reflect the changes instantly to all the other sheets.